# How to find word with the greatest number of different letters?

Tags: c++

For example: I have a string:

> abcdef aaaaaaa bbbbbb

and program should output

> abcdef

because it's the word with the greatest number of different letters.

How can I do this?

---

This is the attempt I made

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    string a;
    int count = 0;
    getline(cin, a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if (a[i] == ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count+1;
}
```

Comment: you can use a `std::set` to count letters.

Comment: Somebody has already given you a clue how to check each letter in the string. I can't help you think about it!

Comment: your code is not anywhere close to the final solution. Please try to focus your question on one specifc issue. That could be eg "how to split the input into words?" or "how to count different letters in a word?"

Comment: Let's get nuts and just say that you *could* use `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::set<char>>>`, and then `std::sort` it with a lambda! Or a `std::set` of pairs of strings and sets; this lets you embed the sorting instead of doing it later. Or maybe it's just easier to count values in an array. How you can do it will vary *wildly* on your actual requirements and restraints.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do it is to use [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream#:%7E:text=Definition-,stringstream,-basic_stringstream%3Cchar%3E) to split your string into words.

After that, as already suggested in comments, you could use [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to count the letters numbers since each element in `std::set` is unique.

A possible solution would be:

```
std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> max_letters_word(const std::string & s)
{
    std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> result {"", 0};

    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string word;
    std::set<char> set;

    while(ss >> word)
    {
        for(char c : word)
            set.insert(c);

        if(set.size() > result.second)
        {
            result.first = word;
            result.second = set.size();
        }
        set.clear();
    }

    return result;
}
```

And you could use this function as follows:

```
int main()
{
    // Considering this string
    std::string s = "abcdef aaaaaaaaa bbbuubbb";

    // Call max_letters_word()
    std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> result = max_letters_word(s);
    
    // Display the result
    std::cout << result.first << ": " << result.second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/xKbTzoj66)

Answer (score -3):

With any programming language, "How can I do *x*?" can have a **lot** of different answers. Some languages, like python try to lull into the idea that there is one correct (or pythonic as they say) way of doing things, but it's still not true. To python's credit, they usually have a lot less variation than C++ can have.

That is to say, it's a bad question. You need to let us know what your requirements and restrictions are. That allows people to provide solutions that can actually work for you.

Break down the task into sub-tasks. Break the sub-tasks down. Figure out what your algorithm is before writing any code. At a high level, it looks like you need to:

- Split the line into individual words
- Count the unique characters in each word

  - Keep track while counting to know which word has the most unique characters
- Print the word with the most unique characters

You need to break those tasks down further until you arrive at something you can do. Then do it, and move on. Eventually you'll have a complete program.

If I were to guess, this solution is probably not what you're looking for:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::size_t count_unique_chars(std::string word) {
  for (auto& i : word) {
    i = std::toupper(i);
  }

  std::sort(word.begin(), word.end());
  word.erase(std::unique(word.begin(), word.end()), word.end());

  return word.length();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) return 1;

  std::string stringLine = argv[1];
  std::stringstream stream(stringLine);
  std::vector<std::string> words;

  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream),
            std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), std::back_inserter(words));

  int maxUniqueChars = 0;
  std::string wordWithMostUniqueChars;
  for (auto i : words) {
    int charCount = count_unique_chars(i);
    if (charCount > maxUniqueChars) {
      maxUniqueChars = charCount;
      wordWithMostUniqueChars = i;
    }
  }

  std::cout << wordWithMostUniqueChars << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
❯ ./a.out "abcdef aaaaaaa bbbbbb"
abcdef

❯ ./a.out "cat cattttttt cats"
cats
```

It works, but this looks like a homework problem and most of that code probably flies right over your head. So it doesn't really help you.

I can make some assumptions, but even they might be off. I'm just trying to highlight how much work goes into asking the right questions. It may sound super-annoying, but there are nothing but benefits. Formulating a "good" question requires you to put in effort. That effort comes across in the asking, and when people get a well-formulated question, they will recognize your effort and be more willing to help. It's also easier to answer a well formulated question.

Here's another program that uses a different tactic.

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::size_t count_unique_chars(std::string word) {
  std::vector<char> letters(26, 0);

  for (auto i : word) {
    char c = std::toupper(i);
    ++letters[c - 'A'];
  }

  int count = 0;
  for (auto i : letters) {
    if (i > 0) ++count;
  }

  return count;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) return 1;

  std::string stringLine = argv[1];
  std::vector<std::string> words;

  while (stringLine.size() > 0) {
    std::size_t idx = stringLine.find_last_of(" ");
    std::string word = stringLine.substr(idx + 1);
    words.push_back(word);
    if (idx == std::string::npos) idx = 0;
    stringLine.erase(idx);
  }

  std::size_t maxUniqueChars = 0;
  std::string wordWithMostUniqueChars;
  for (auto i : words) {
    std::size_t count = count_unique_chars(i);
    if (count > maxUniqueChars) {
      maxUniqueChars = count;
      wordWithMostUniqueChars = i;
    }
  }

  std::cout << wordWithMostUniqueChars << '\n';
}
```

It still relies on taking advantage of `std::string` and what it offers, which might not fit with your restrictions.

Both programs follow the high-level steps outlined above. Both programs work, but go about executing the algorithm in different ways. Having clear requirements, and knowing what restrictions are in place will also steer you toward a solution.

Comment: "*most of that code probably flies right over your head. So it doesn't really help you.*". Then why share it?

Comment: I feel that reading the entire answer provides the context.

Answer (score -4):

Yeah we can do this.. Following is the code which can help you out.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
string s;
getline(cin,s);
s=s+' ';
string word="";
int ans=0;
map<int,string> mp;
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
    char ch=s[i];
    if(s[i]!=' ')
        word=word+ch;
    else{
        int c=0;
        for(int j=0;j<word.length()-1;j++){
            if(word[j]!=word[j+1])
                c++;
        }
        ans=max(ans,c);
        mp[c]=word;
        word="";
    }
}
cout<<mp[ans];

}
```

Comment: Please format the code. And also please don't encourage the use `<bits/stdc++.h>` or `using namespace std;`. They're poor practice. There are a couple other less-than-ideal things going on as well.

Comment: I just do the algorithm. If you don't wanna use 'using namespace std;' just don't use it.
Also the code is formatted.

Comment: Let me clear something..
1.My intention is not to show how clever I am,I just give one of my approach.
2.Talking about the actual code I used a simple data structure i.e. MAP and a simple approach. The map which I used is to  keep the track of maximum distinct characters which each word hold and then using the value of maximum distinct character to access that particular word,that's it.
3.Talking about the variables names,I know that is not much descriptive but it doesn't mean I am showing myself how clever I am.

Comment: A description of the code and what the algorithm does should be part of the answer, not a comment.

Comment: Okay then I think so I share my approach or the algorithmic description of my code.